# How to add Latin Words into an index

Tags: indexing

I have the following in my preamble

```
\usepackage[latin, english]{babel}
```

(for proper hyphenation) and then

```
\newcommand{\latin}[1]{\foreignlanguage{latin}{\emph{#1}}}
```

when I write `\latin{ultra vires}` 
it prints correctly.

The issue I am having is if I wish to index this I can do

```
\latin{ultra vires}\index{ultra vires}
```

but this outputs without the latin italicised

Is there a way to index with it being printed in the index as it has in the body when i did `\latin{ultra vires}`

I hope this makes sense, I am new to LaTeX.

Comment: Observe that not always `\emph{}` will produce the desired font. Try `\textit{some \emph{latin here}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make anything appear where you want it in an index, by using `\index{<sorting position>@<formatted text>}`

So for your example, you can input `\index{ultra vires@\latin{ultra vires}}`

You probably want to write a macro for this - for example

`\newcommand{\latinindex}[1]{\index{#1@\latin{#1}}}`

Comment: thanks `\index{ultra vires@\latin{ultra vires}}` didn't work with my setup but writing the new macro you suggested worked perfectly and resolved my problem. Thanks.